# A wizard's logical behavior

Tags: wizard, design-decisions

The question I have is about the general functionality of the back button in wizards. I was thinking about the possible behaviors of this button and I couldn't find any clue which one is the right choice between these two options.

1- It should show the previous page and the changes made in the current form shouldn't be saved.

2- It should show the previous page and the changes made in the current form should be saved.

I would like to know which option you think is the correct behavior for the back button and why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pretty sensible Windows guideline from Microsoft is;

> **Preserve user selections through navigation**.
>
> For example, if the user
>   makes changes, clicks Back and then Next, those changes should be
>   preserved. Users don't expect to have to re-enter changes unless they
>   explicitly chose to clear them.

See [UX Wizards guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa511260.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the very informative response. After reading the link I came across another hint that says. `don't confuse navigational buttons (Next and Back) with commit buttons. Next means to progress in the wizard without commitment; Back should always be available on the next page, and clicking Back should undo the effect of the last Next button` So does this imply that committing changes are different from preserving them?

Comment: Yea, if a page causes X to happen (committing - say creating a registry entry) based on a value in a textbox then going forward then back again should undo X but keep the value in the textbox the same